# How can I submit an array of item numbers to query a mongoDB collection and return all requested docs as array of objects?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, async-await, mongodb-query

My query is an array of numbers that I want to pull from a collection. I can map over the array and pull the needed docs, but it will not update the original array (also used spread operator) or save and/or return a new array. I found that `Promise.all` something about `aggregate` might be solutions, but I am not really sure how to implement. The mongoDB connections are all good and the client request is an array, but an `async map` is not practical. How can this be accomplished in a single request?

```
const Purchase = require('../models/purchase.model') 


//Get user purchases
const getPurchases = async(req, res) => {
    let purchases = req.body.purchases;
    console.log(purchases)

    purchases.map(async(p, index) => {
        console.log(purchases)
        const purchase = await Purchase.findOne({
            trans_no: p
        })
        
        const purchaseObj = {
            date: purchase.date,
            total: purchase.total,
            merchant_name: purchase.merchant_name,
            merchant_id: purchase.merchant_id,
            mop: purchase.mop,
            items: purchase.items,
            trans_no: purchase.trans_no
        }
        console.log(purchaseObj)
        purchases[index] = purchaseObj
    })
    
    if (purchases.length > 0) {
        return res.json({ 
            status: 'ok', 
            purchases
        })
    } else {
        return res.json({ status: 'error', purchase: false })
    }
    
}

module.exports = { getPurchases }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in one request using `Purchase.find()` and the `$in` keyword. This method will return an array of purchases:

```
Purchase.find({
    'trans_no': { $in: purchases }
}, function(err, docs){
     console.log(docs);
});
```

Your code will be something like:

```
const Purchase = require('../models/purchase.model') 


//Get user purchases
const getPurchases = async(req, res) => {
    let purchases = req.body.purchases;
    console.log(purchases)

    const dbPurchases = await Purchase.find({
        'trans_no': { $in: purchases }
    });
    dbPurchases.map((purchase, index) => {         
        const purchaseObj = {
            date: purchase.date,
            total: purchase.total,
            merchant_name: purchase.merchant_name,
            merchant_id: purchase.merchant_id,
            mop: purchase.mop,
            items: purchase.items,
            trans_no: purchase.trans_no
        }
        console.log(purchaseObj)
        purchases[index] = purchaseObj
    })
    
    if (purchases.length > 0) {
        return res.json({ 
            status: 'ok', 
            purchases
        })
    } else {
        return res.json({ status: 'error', purchase: false })
    }
    
}

module.exports = { getPurchases }
```

You can simplify this code and add a `try/catch` to make it more robust :)

Comment: Please do simplify. It would help to see how it can be more "robust". The code above is based off my limited knowledge, so I am all for something more efficient.